# Positioning a node relative to the center of another node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I position the node 's2' above 's1' so that leftmost 0 (of node 's2') is exactly above and at center of 's1'

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,fill=cyan!40,minimum size=1.2cm,rectangle,yshift=.5cm] at (current page.center) 
    (s1) {q};

    \node[draw=none,above=of s1,anchor=south west] (s2) {0 0 0 1 1 1};
    \draw[->] (s1) -- (s2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to anchor the node to the south west (as you have done), then shift it to the left by the amount necessary to align the first zero:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\zerooffset}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,fill=cyan!40,minimum size=1.2cm,rectangle,yshift=.5cm] at (current page.center) 
    (s1) {q};
    \setlength{\zerooffset}{\widthof{0}}%<=== get the width of the 0
    \node[draw=none,above= of s1,anchor=south west,xshift={\dimexpr-0.5\zerooffset-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}] (s2) {0 0 0 1 1 1};
    \draw[->] (s1) -- (s2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered first zero]

And if you want the arrow to be vertical:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\zerooffset}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,fill=cyan!40,minimum size=1.2cm,rectangle,yshift=.5cm] at (current page.center) 
    (s1) {q};
    \setlength{\zerooffset}{\widthof{0}}%<=== get the width of the 0
    \node[draw=none,above= of s1,anchor=south west,xshift={\dimexpr-0.5\zerooffset-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}] (s2) {0 0 0 1 1 1};
    \draw[->] let \p1=(s1.north),\p2=(s2.south) in (\x1,\y1)--(\x1,\y2);%<=== vertical arrow
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered with vertical arrow]

Comment: +1 I think this is the only solution. Because in the original code the left edge of the node *is* aligned with the centre of the lower node, so aligning with something inside the node must be done (semi-)manually.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Given the flexibility of TeX in general, I'm always hesitant to say *only*. That being said, I agree that some degree of manual intervention is necessary for this effect.

Comment: Yes, you're right, never say 'never'. :) (And a new answer has already appeared.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I have split the node with the text into two, which allows to position them as required. Notice the `\smallskipamount` which corresponds to the space between the zeros.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[draw,fill=cyan!40,minimum size=1.2cm,rectangle,yshift=.5cm] at (current page.center) (s1) {q};

        \node[draw=none,above=of s1] (s2) {0};
        \node[draw=none,right=\smallskipamount] at (s2) {0 0 1 1 1};

        \draw[->] (s1) -- (s2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]